# How to use object to hold array and use against another array?

Tags: c#

Create a class `HugeInteger` which uses a 40-element array of digits to store integers as large as 40 digits each.

- Provide methods `Input()`, `ToString()`, `Add()` and `Subtract()`.
- For comparing `HugeInteger` objects, provide the following methods: `IsEqualTo()`, `IsNotEqualTo()`, `IsGreaterThan()`, `IsLessThan()`, `IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo()` and `IsLessThanOrEqualTo()`.

Each of these is a method that returns true if the relationship holds between the two `HugeInteger` objects and returns false if the relationship does not hold.

- Provide method `IsZero()`.
- In the `Input()` method, use the string method `ToCharArray()` to convert the input string into an array of characters, then iterate through these characters to create your `HugeInteger`.

So far, I've created this:

```
    public const int HUGE_INTEGER_LIMIT = 40;
    private int[] hiDigits = new int[HUGE_INTEGER_LIMIT];
    private int hiLength;
    private string hugeInteger;
    private bool isPositive = true;



    //constructor
    public HugeInteger()
    {
        hiDigits = new int[HUGE_INTEGER_LIMIT];
        isPositive = true;
    }

    public HugeInteger (int[] hi)
    {
        hiDigits = hi;
    }

    public void Input(string input)
    {
        hiDigits =  input.Select(x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x)).ToArray();
        //char[] hiChars = input.ToCharArray();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string num = "";
        foreach (int n in hiDigits)
        {
            num = num + n;
        }
        return num;
    }

    public HugeInteger Add(HugeInteger val)
    {
        var result = new HugeInteger();

        for (int i = 0; i < HUGE_INTEGER_LIMIT; i++)
        {
            result.hiDigits[i] = 0;
            result.hiDigits[i] += val.hiDigits[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But I am stuck in how to add these `hiDigits` array.

Am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: You are not accounting for the place value, so when adding a number in 10's place you should add them together and store the units place in result in that location and carry over the 10's place number to the next place. It would help if you run the loop in reverse. That is from 39 to 0 index, assuming a39 index in your units place

Comment: ahhhh, does this work?  for (int i = val.hiLength-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                result.hiDigits[i] = 0;
                result.hiDigits[i] += val.hiDigits[i];
            }